Storing time and timezone data in PostgreSQL
Our users should be able to configure a time-in-day, and a timezone, by which they want to get daily updates. The updates should contain data that will be presented in their timezone of choice. For that, we probably want to store time & timezone data, per user.
I understand timetz is discourage since it doesn't take daylight savings into account. I also understand it's necessary to store timezone string (like EST) and not offset (like UTC+10.
I can use time for the time part, and text for the timezone string, but it means I will have to sanitize the timezone data in code, which I'm trying to avoid.
What's the best practice here?

Using zone names like EST does not solve the issue, because in summer that will become EDT. Store the timezone as a location, e.g. Asia/Tokyo in my case.

I see. But does text type my best option?

What is an appropriate data type to store a timezone?
